# "Take more, throw further" - an idiom about a dumb work

Tags: phrase-request, idioms, idiom-request

There is a saying in Russian, which could be translated as:

> Take more, throw further, take a rest while it flies

Initially, it was applied to a manual digging with a shovel to demonstrate that this kind of work has nothing hard to understand and doesn't require to be very clever. Just take a shovel and dig. But nowadays it is often used to describe any kind of a dumb work. For example, when your boss is asking you to concentrate on quantity instead of quality. If you are a programmer, you need to write more code and doesn't matter, how fast it works and how much bugs it has; if you are selling cars, you need to call all the clients and propose them everything you have, and doesn't matter what impression they will have after, etc. So you can say about this: It is just a dumb work in "take more, throw further" style.

Is there an idiom in English or any other way to say this in one phrase?

Comment: Seems related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/44545/193515

Comment: Thank you very much. It is very close to what I need, but not exactly the same, unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a well-known saying *quality over quantity* - meaning one should care about how well something is done rather than the amount it is done.

You can use the reverse version of this saying.  It's typically implied that the situation is not the best.

> We just need to call everyone today no matter what.  Quantity over quality for now, unfortunately.

---

> If you are a programmer, you need to write more code and doesn't matter, how fast it works and how much bugs it has

The "business-friendly" way of expressing this is *time to market* - meaning getting something out quickly and fixing later is more important that getting something out with no issues.

> Finish the code.  We'll fix bugs in an update.  Need to keep time to market in mind.